# Visual Studio Code - powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute Not Working

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

The Video Studio Code (VSC) flag to automatically move the focus to the terminal when getting input in a PowerShell script isn’t working.

I have **powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute** checked (true), but the focus stays in the editor pane when I debug a script. I have to remember to manually move the focus to the terminal when the script requests user input (e.g., **Read-Host**), or else my input overwrites whatever is selected in the editor pane.

I’m running **VSC version 1.81.0**. My PSVersionTable:

```
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

I’ve submitted a [VSC bug report](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/4691), but would love to cancel it if someone can show me an easy fix for this problem.

Here's are some of the error messages that have appeared in the last few minutes:

[image: Debug Adapter Error]

[image: Language Server Error]

Another strange thing is that the debugger seems to work OK, despite the scary error message.

Another symptom I just noticed: When I’m looking at the source code, the “reference count” normally displayed in the line above function names is missing.

The error messages seem to point at the PowerShell extension as the culprit.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I have Windows 10, so perhaps that's part of the problem.

Comment: Just heard back from my VSC bug report. They said the problem is due to an extension, but didn't say which one. They told me to run "extension bisect," which failed with an error message that said I couldn't run the script because the PowerShell extension was missing.

Comment: Curious, but good to know the cause in principle. Assuming you don't have too many extensions, you can try disabling them one by one until the problem goes away, as described in section 'Finding a "bad" extension the hard way' of help topic [Resolving extension issues with bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect)

Comment: I was hopeful once I learned of the bisect tool. Unfortunately, the minute I ran it, VSC said it couldn’t run because the PowerShell extension was disabled [by the bisect tool]! It was a Catch 22, chicken-and-egg problem. So I ended up re-submitting the issue report on the PowerShell extension (vice VSC). Still waiting to see what comes of that.

Comment: So have you tried without the bisect tool and have you disabled the other extensions one by one?

Comment: Yes. I tried the bisect tool. But the minute I did, it told me the script couldn't run because the PowerShell extension was diasbled. Catch 22.

Comment: I understand, but my question was whether you have tried _without_ the bisect tool, by _manually disabling_ the other extensions, _one by one_, as described in the linked help topic.

Comment: No, but someone at GitHub suggested it was probably the PowerShell extension at fault. The Bisect tool from the menu was so painful to use that I'm going to wait for the outcome of my PowersShell extension issue report before monkeying with anything else. I'm currently having HUGE functional issues with VSC, and don't want to add to my woes. (Just submitted a different question on a gratuitous landslide of debug info whenever I start VSC). Sigh…

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to find it this morning, and realized I don't know how to find it. I'd paste it in if I knew how to find it. Sadly, I've never used Github, and my brain is almost full just trying to learn PowerShell right now. If it gets any fuller, I'm going to have to forget 5th grade. 8=)

Comment: A new clue just appeared. While VSC was open a dialog suddenly opened and announced “PowerShell Language Server process didn't start.” I assume that's a bad thing. Don't have a clue how serious the issue is. Does Stackoverflow have a way to upload an image of the error message?

Comment: I've added the link to your bug report to the question. Yes, you need the language server for debugging. Yes, you can upload or paste images here. The toolbar in edit mode has an icon for it (a stylized mountain scene with black background).

Comment: Now another clue emerged. When I tried to debug just now, a VSC error dialog opened saying “Couldn't find a debug adapter descriptor for debug type 'PowerShell' (extension might have failed to activate).” Is is this just another symptom of the same problem? What caused the extension to suddenly go south?

Comment: I was referring to editing posts _here on Stack Overflow_, but I see that you've already figured out how to add images to posts.

Comment: I realize that I initially missed the breakpoint angle, and I suspect the behavior is by (debatable) design - I'll post a comment on your bug report. Note that your later problems are a separate problem, for which I have no explanation, but perhaps reinstalling the PowerShell extension helps.

Comment: Will uninstalling and reinstalling the PowerShell extension erase my existing code?

Comment: You mean code in `.ps1` files etc. that you've created? No.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The additional symptoms mentioned in your question that you added later (error dialogs popping up) are unrelated to your original issue; this answers focuses only on the latter.

---

The current behavior of the `powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute`  setting when set to `true` (the default), is ***possibly* by design** (I can't speak to that):

- The setting applies ***when debugging starts*: the input focus moves to Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal**...
- ... **and *stays there*** (even after debugging ends) **UNLESS a breakpoint is hit**, in which case the **focus moves back to the editor pane and stays there**.

**Why would you want the focus to move back to the editor when a breakpoint is hit?** Here are a few reasons (there may be more):

- Hovering over variables to show their current value only works if the editor has the focus.
- Keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>F12</kbd> to jump to a variable's definition only work if the editor has the focus.
- You may want to edit the line with the breakpoint or other lines nearby (even though such changes don't take effect in the same debugging session).

---

De facto, users may have come to expect and rely on this behavior, so changing it would be problematic, I think.

A non-breaking option would be for the maintainers of the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) to change the setting from a Boolean to an integer, where, say, `2`  could signal the intent to place the focus in the integrated terminal *and leave it there*, even when breakpoints are hit.

I've added these clarifications to [your bug report](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/4691) too; that report may therefore lead to a feature request.

Comment: I like your idea of making the setting non-boolean. Offers more flexibility at little cost.

Comment: I uninstalled the PowerShell Extension, closed Visual Studio Code (VSC), reopened VSC, & opened a code file. Then the “Power Shell Language Server process didn't start” error popped up again. Is the PowerShell Language Server not part of the PowerShell extension? Do I need to install it separately?

Comment: I notice the “reference count” is still missing from above function names, as well.

Comment: @aksarben, it is indeed a part of the PowerShell extension and does not need to be installed separately. I have no explanation for your symptoms, but I suggest (a) removing the references to your later symptoms from the initial post and (b) posting an issue with the later symptoms either here or in the relevant repo. As for "reference count": If the language server isn't running, that absence is to be expected.

Comment: I'm starting to have equally inexplicable symptoms in other parts of my computer not connected to PowerShell. I'm beginning to think it may be time to replace the machine, which is 4½ years old. But first I'm going to try uninstalling, then re-installing a fresh download of VSC. Do you have a recommended site where I can safely download VSC? Don't recall where I got it last time.

Comment: Sorry to hear it, @aksarben, https://code.visualstudio.com/ is the official site.